# Tracking Duplicates Based Specific Criteria In a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

**Task**

I would like to track duplicate rows based on the `item column`. I would also like to add a column that states if it is repeated `repeated ?`.I've used the duplicate function but it just returns true or false, I would like to return the entire column where the condition is met. ps5 is the targeted item that repeats in the item list.

```
item   price   serial        repeated ?
----   ----     ----          ----
ps5    499     p413          True

ps5    399     p412          True

xsx    499     x720          False

xss    299     x360          False
```

**Expected Result**

```
ps5    499     p413     True     

ps5    399     p412     True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
tmp = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,2,4], [1,2,3]], columns=['a','b','c'])
repeated = tmp.duplicated('b', keep=False)
tmp[repeated]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html